# OS X - Configure Eclipse Luna to use CLI maven repository

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, osx-yosemite

I have installed Eclipse luna on my macbook(with Yosemite).  Maven in eclipse works fine. Prior to that i installed maven in system (extracted downloaded package and set in the path). Both (Eclipse based and CLI based) maven works fine.  Following are questions.

1. I suspect that, both maven tools use separate directories to store downloaded files. Which may eat up lot of space.  Is it true?
2. Is there any way we can configure eclipse maven plugin to use maven installed by me or atleast use the same directory to save the space.

Will be thankful for any pointer.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way would be by using [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/). Do you have it installed?
Then you could do:

```
brew install maven
```

Then you can install the maven plugins on Eclipse, but I think Luna already comes with the bundle, si you just need to try. 
Hope it helps!